# Piping commands in a shell script

Tags: shell

I want to write a script that opens a shell with a few tabs, and i want each tab to execute somthing automaticly. for some reason when i pipe the commands it does not work.

```
gnome-terminal \
    --tab-with-profile=Titleable -t "A" \
    --tab-with-profile=Titleable -t "B" -e "sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog" \
    --tab-with-profile=Titleable -t "C" -e "sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep txt"
```

for some reason for Tab A&B work but in C the grep txt is ignored.

Anyone know why?

Thanks
Mat

Answer (score 0):

Use a shell to call your command:

```
gnome-terminal \
    --tab-with-profile=Titleable -t "A" \
    --tab-with-profile=Titleable -t "B" -e "sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog" \
    --tab-with-profile=Titleable -t "C" -e 'sh -c "sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep txt"'
```

Comment: @user690936 Using a shell to call the command worked well with me. Any error you see?

Comment: @user690936 I mean this: `-e 'sh -c "sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep txt"'`. That's not part of your original command.

Comment: @user690936 It doesn't ignore. Perhaps you're just not seeing any output yet because of grep?

Comment: maybe... but it does not help me if i don't see it :)

Comment: @user690936 That act is kind of lame. Good luck.

Comment: @user690936 To get a message containing `txt`, run something like `logger txt`.